# Dirac delta composed with a function and implicit equation for the roots

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I'm considering an expression of the form
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx G(x) \delta(x^2-f(x)^2) $$
where $G$ and $f$ are two unrelated smooth functions of $x$. Now I know that when $f$ is a positive constant, I can write this as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{G(x)}{2f} (\delta(x-f)+\delta(x+f)).
$$

Now, f is a function of $x$ and I do not have an explicit form of the roots of $x^2-f(x)^2$, but I do have the implicit equations $x=f(x)$ and $x=-f(x)$ for the roots. Can I write my first expression in a form similar to the second equation? That is, I would like to split the Dirac delta in the first expression and end up with something like

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx H(x) \left(\delta(x-f(x))+\delta(x+f(x))\right).
$$
where $H$ is some known function of $x$ (and $G(x)$ and $f(x)$).